# Passing objects to DI in group isnt it a bad sign?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

basic form of DI:

```
class TestClass
{
    private $obj;

    public function __constructor($obj)
    {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }
}
```

but what if I have to pass 20 objects, coming from the same origin and I cant know which one will be used? So, it would be a database models:

```
class Testt
{
    private $forum, $forumThread, $users, $posts;

    public function __constructor($forum, $forumThread, $users, $posts)
    {
        $this->forum = $forum;
        $this->forumThread = $forumThread;
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }
}
```

anytime when a new model presents, this code changes. Not to mention if there are more Test* classes. But what if I do

```
class Models
{
    private $forum, $forumThread, $users, $posts;

    public function __constructor($forum, $forumThread, $users, $posts)
    {
        $this->forum = $forum;
        $this->forumThread = $forumThread;
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }
}

class Test
{
    private $models;

    public function __constructor(Model $models)
    {
        $this->models = $models;
    }
}
```

it would be the best, isnt it? Sadly I havent seen any article groupping classes that way.

Comment: If you need to pass 20 objects to a class, you need to rethink your design. If one class have that many dependencies, it's doing too much. You should break it up in several classes where each class have a specific responsibility.

Comment: BTW, it's `__construct()`, not `__constructor()`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Im aware of that, but the problem is these objects comes from the same origins (Model) and I cant know which will be used, so all must be passed

Comment: I'm not following you. What do you mean by _"the same origins"_? And how can you not know which will be used? Can you give as a real example?